# Definition of standard functions

Tags: calculus, functions, definition, elementary-functions

In many texts and books about calculus we see

> There are functions $f$ for which the anti-derivative cannot be
>   expressed in terms of *standard functions* or there are many
>   integrals that cannot be expressed in terms of *standard functions*.

What functions are called *standard functions* and why?

Comment: See [What makes elementary functions elementary?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118113/what-makes-elementary-functions-elementary).

Comment: Are standard functions exactly the same elementary functions?

Comment: There is a technical sense used by those who research this area in which "elementary function" also includes all functions $y$ that can be the solution to some algebraic equation with rational function coefficients and $y$ as the unknown variable in the equation, and this meaning will include some functions that can't be explicitly expressed as a finite combination of (additions, multiplications, compositions) of the kinds of functions you're used to seeing. I suspect, however, that "standard function" for your author doesn't mean this, but rather just means explicitly representable this way.