# About a classic "primitive"

Tags: calculus, reference-request

A long time ago I heard somethings about the following primitive $\int e^{x^2} \ dx$ :

1 ) It doens't exist

2) It cannot be expressed by means of "elementary functions"

Someone could point me a reference about the existence (if possible a reference that treats about the explicit form) of this primitive? What is the precise meaning of the term "elementary functions" ?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Certainly this function has a primitive, namely, $\int_{x_0}^x e^{t^2} dt$, for example (any other differs from this one by a constant). As for "elementary functions", see this popular question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118113/what-makes-elementary-functions-elementary

Comment: But this integral have an "explicit" form  ?

Comment: Do you mean one not involving a definite integral? In that case, it depends on which functions you allow. One can write a primitive in terms of the Dawson function---http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function---but that's more or less a tautology, as it's usually defined to be (a modification of) that primitive in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just mean that it cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions like 
$$
5x^{3}-2x+3, \log[x], e^{x}, \sin[x],5^{x}\cdots 
$$
which are the ones we encountered in a typical calculus I class. The typical function of the type you mentioned is
$$
\frac{\sin[x]}{x}
$$
And it is not too difficult to change your integral to something close to this form.

The sub-branch that deal with whether an explicit integral can be obtained using elementary functions is called [differential algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra). The major tool is [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)). Regrettably, the founder of the subject, [Joseph Ritt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Ritt) committed suicide despite his monumental mathematical work.