# What is special about a function being elementary?

Tags: trigonometry, elementary-functions, error-function

Functions such as $ \sin(x) $ are considered to be elementary, however functions like $ \text{erf}(x) $ are considered to be non-elementary.

What makes elementary functions different from non-elementary functions, both $ \sin(x) $ and $ \text{erf}(x) $ can only be expressed as an infinite sum containing the 4 basic operations, division, multiplication, addition, and subtraction. Is what makes a function elementary a purely arbitrary decision?

Comment: History.${}{}{}$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118113/what-makes-elementary-functions-elementary)

Comment: My understanding is that $\sin(x)$ has many properties from $e^{ix} $ to sides of triangle to the circles/polar coordinates. I'd say $\sin$ is an understood function while stuff like $erf$ not so much.