# Is it possible to find the explicit representation of the integral of $f'(x)=e^{ae^{bx}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I come across a problem to find $f$ such that $f'(x)=e^{ae^{bx}}$ for constants $a$ and $b$.

I think $f(x)$ should have the form $c_1e^{c_2e^{c_3x}}$ (ignoring the indefinite constant), but it seems not working. Is there any other thought on it?

Comment: Where did you got the problem? The integral of this function is not any elementary function...

Comment: Title and body are different.  If you want the integral of $f'$ as in your title, I can handle that.

Comment: It comes from the problem that finding $y(x)$ such that $y'(x)=1-cy(x)e^{-dx}$ and $y(0)=0$ with positive constants $c,d$. After multiplying an integrating factor, it turns out to be this problem.

Comment: The problem is to find an explicit representation of $f(x)$ so that its derivative $f'(x)=\exp(a\exp(bx))$.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using the ["Exponential integral"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) function $\operatorname{Ei}_1(z)$, which may be defined by:
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\operatorname{Ei}_1(z) = -\frac{e^{-z}}{z},\qquad\lim_{z \to +\infty}\operatorname{Ei}_1(z) = 0
\tag1$$
or, equivalently for $z>0$,
$$
\operatorname{Ei}_1(z) = \int_z^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-s}}{s}\;ds =
\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-tz}\frac{dt}{t} .
\tag2$$

Define
$$
F(x) = -\frac{\operatorname{Ei}_1\left(-ae^{bx}\right)}{b} .
\tag3$$
Differentiate using $(1)$ to get
$$
F'(x) = \exp\left(a e^{bx}\right)
$$
so $(3)$ is our answer.

---

It is known that $\operatorname{Ei}_1$ is not an [elementary function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118113/what-makes-elementary-functions-elementary/118258#118258).
For the OP we cannot expect an elementary function answer, such as $c_1e^{c_2e^{c_3x}}$.