# Elementary function that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x>0$.

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

Here is a short question: finding a function that 1) $f(0)=1$ and 2) $f(x)=0$ for all $x>0$.

I have two functions in mind:

1. Something like Dirac delta: $\delta_0(x)$.
2. Something like $f(x)=1-\text{sign}(x)$.

But they are (arguably) not elementary. A function that is simpler and more elementary will be appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use the function you defined?  It's not the dirac delta (as that "function" is certainly not defined at $0$).  You can define it any way you like for $x<0$ (or leave it undefined if you prefer).

Comment: What functions do you consider elementary?

Comment: @paperskilltrees Any simple functions that are learned or easily understood by high-schoolers. I think it might be impossible as any operations learned in high school are continuous, and this function is not continuous.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Or maybe we can use the definition here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118113/what-makes-elementary-functions-elementary

Comment: You are absolutely correct in that observation! Any sum, product, superposition etc of continuous functions is continuous. Division by zero won't give you the kind of discontinuity you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the example

$$f(x)=\lfloor e^{-x} \rfloor$$

So

$$f(0)=\lfloor 1\rfloor=1$$
and for $ x>0$

$$0<e^{-x}<1\implies f(x)=0$$

Comment: Are you sure that floor function is elementary?