# Book recommendation on special functions

Tags: special-functions, book-recommendation

I am currently studying real analysis from rudin and really like the chapter on special functions. But Rudin does not give much knowledge about those topics. Reading the references I found book by Emil artin on The Gamma function and really liked it. Are there more books like Emil artin's gamma function on special functions.

Comment: The answers to [What is a special function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/what-is-a-special-function) have a few book mentions, mostly of a reference kind.

Comment: From the short bibliography  page 29 in "Safari in the Country of special Functions": https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales \\ [9] : N.Ja.Vilenkine, Fonctions spéciales et théorie de représentation des groupes, Edit.
Dunod, 1969.
\\ [10] : A. Nikiforov, Elements de la théorie des fonctions spéciales, Edit. MIR (Moscou),
1976.
\\ [11] : P.Appell, J.Kampe de Feriet, Fonctions hypergéométriques et hypersphériques;
Polynômes d'Hermite, Gauthier-Villar edit., 1926.

Comment: \\ [5] : M.Abramowitz, I.A.Stegun, Handbook of Mathematical Functions, Dover Publications,
N.-Y., 1972
\\ [6] : H.Batemann, Higher Transcendental Functions (3 volumes), Edit. Mc. Graw-Hill, N.-
Y.,1953.
\\ [7] : H.Batemann, Tables of Integral Transforms, Integrals of Higher Transcendental
Functions, Vol.2, pp.263-447, Edit. Mc. Graw-Hill, N.-Y.,1954.

Answer (score 2):

The second half of Whittaker and Watson's [*A Course of Modern Analysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis)  is devoted to special functions.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [Special Functions and Orthogonal Polynomials](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Functions-Orthogonal-Polynomials-Cambridge-Mathematics/dp/1107106982/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1540748172&sr=1-1&keywords=special+functions+advanced+mathematics) for reference on special functions.